# Android managing items on AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have this situation.

On my layout I have 3 buttons and one radiogroup with two radiobuttons.
The user must press `button1`, `button2`, pick one of the radiobuttons and after that, it will press `button3` and a query to a database will be performed.

After pressing `button1`, a query will be performed and the result will be shown on an MultipleChoiceItems AlertDialog.

I have some questions.

**MultipleChoiceItems**

I have three problems with this AlertDialog.

First:
The query result is shown on my AlertDialog but if I press any of the items no checkmark is placed on the checkbox. I can see in my toast message that the items is being checked.

Second:
The query is perform to the database but can I add one element that is not returned by the query?
Imagine the AlertDialog, after the query, shows `One`,`Two`,`Three`. I want to add one more item. Something like `This was not returned by the query`,`One`,`Two`,`Three`.

Third:

`public AlertDialog.Builder setMultiChoiceItems (Cursor cursor, String isCheckedColumn, String labelColumn, DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener)` second parameter is to set the items checked or unchecked. My database does not have this column so I've passed one column that I know it is always different than zero. Is there a way to bypass this?

This is my code:

```
public class MyClass extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener {
    Database db = new Database(this);
    int order;
    boolean groupCheck = false;
    boolean orderCheck = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.n);

        Button proc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.procButtonProc);
        proc.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button pickGroup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.procButtonGroup);
        pickGroup.setOnClickListener(this);
        RadioGroup pickOrder = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.procRadioOrder);
        pickOrder.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.procButtonGroup) {

            db.open();
            final Cursor query = db.getData(0, 0, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder pickGroup = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            pickGroup.setTitle(getString(R.string.procGroupTitle));

            pickGroup.setMultiChoiceItems(query, "GROUP_NAME", "GROUP_NAME", new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (isChecked) {
                        query.moveToPosition(which);
                        String str = query.getString(1).toString();
                        Toast.makeText(MyClass.this, "You have selected " + str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // ListView list = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                        // list.setItemChecked(which, true);

                    }
                }
            });

            pickGroup.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });

            pickGroup.show();
            db.close();

        } 

        if (v.getId() == R.id.procButtonProc) {

            if (orderCheck == true && groupCheck == true) {
                // Based on the conditions, perform query on the database

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select GROUP, N and ORDER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.procOrderASC:
                order = 0;
                orderCheck = true;
                break;
            case R.id.procOrderDSC:
                order = 1;
                orderCheck = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

favolas